# accessibility issues with .jar file in jtessboxeditor

Tags: tesseract

Hi I have downloaded jtessboxeditor and extracted the files. I downloaded the java runtime environment too. I have opened the jtessboxeditorFX.jar file, is getting popped up, but can't accessible. I used the same application yesterday but today i am facing this issue. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved uninstall and installing java runtime environment followed by restarting the PC. Thanks for viewing the question.